# How to pass a url onclick on item from a recycler view android and onclick getting position dipaly the url of that in another activity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-intent, android-recyclerview

```
public class Product_adapter extends 
            }
        });




    }

    @Override
    pub

        }


    }


}
```

Comment: Hi ! Can we see the code ?

Answer (score -1):

Simply, you can pass the url in the constructor of adapter and use.